# Double Slit in Strong Vacuum

Tags: double-slit-experiment

I'm asking because my wife wants to buy a vacuum pump to do some food preservation so I figured I have an idea for an experiment: do the double slit under a strong vacuum.

I would rather save the money and read the study if it's already been done. **Has this been conducted?**

The reason that I want to do the experiment is: I have a hypothesis to test. I believe that most of, if not all of, the effects observed in the double slit experiment can be explained by classical pnuematics, optics and aerodynamics.

If my hypothesis is correct, then as the vacuum intesity increases, the pneumatic pressure gradient caused by gas molecules coliding with the solid material will dimish and, eventually, disappear. I hypothesize that this gradient, and the pneumatic lense it forms are responsible for altering the flight paths of both the light beams passing through the double slits as well as any attempt at propelling a solid particle through the slits.

This lense is easily observable under normal conditions using your fingers and a light source. You can actually see the lense form as you bring your fingers close together with the light source behind them and if you're really sharp you can see the lense that surrounds your finger. This lense is what causes soft edges on shaddows and the lack of it is why the shaddows you see on space-walks are razor sharp.

It has to be light or bucky balls or something, it can't be an electron beam because then you have electrostatic interference that causes it's own kind of trajectory lensing.

If my hypothesis is incorrect, then quantum mechanical interpretation stands.

My wife wants the vacuum pump any ways, so making the chamber wouldn't be that much extra money, but if it's been done then I don't want to waste my time and money.

Comment: The double slit interference effect has nothing to do with whether it is conducted in vacuum or in air. It is unclear what you are trying to test by creating a vacuum. What do you mean by "pneumatic pressure gradient"?

Comment: In a gas, the surface pressure on an object is caused by the collision of constituent molecules with the solid surface. The molecules colliding with and bouncing off of the solid surface causes a pressure gradient in the gas to form near the surface of the solid. This pneumatic pressure gradient causes https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/edge-diffraction to happen.

Comment: I recommend just deleting the part saying you asked chatgpt. Chatgpt is really bad at physics - it's wrong most of the time and spits out incoherent BS. The users here are tired of answering questions in the form "chatGPT said this, is it right." And the answer is just "no, not in any way whatsoever." For that reason the users here really hate any mention of people asking chatgpt, and some will downvote just because they see "chatgpt" appear in any form.

Comment: Re, "strong vacuum," The kind of vacuum equipment that is sold for food preservation can only achieve what a physicist would call "low vacuum" or "rough vacuum." https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum Under such conditions, the chamber still is considered to be filled with air, but the density of the air is much less than the density of air at atmospheric pressure. It's only when you enter the realm of "high vacuum" and beyond when molecules in the chamber start behaving more like individual particles, and not so much like bulk gas.

Comment: @AXensen Suggestion taken, it's unfortunate because I pay for GPT 4.0 and when you pay for the service, it aggregates web searches from multiple providers and I can often find stuff through GPT 4.0 that would have taken hours of research to find.

It sucks when it hallucinates and misleads you, but I've had less of that issue since I started paying for it and using exclusively GPT 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis is going to be proven false. But I'm never one to discourage someone from trying an enlightening experiment. You should go ahead and do it. But know that your vacuum pump is actually not likely to pull a very good vacuum and you presumably don't have any way to measure how good of a vacuum you can get (probably you have a little dial gauge that will just say "ehh zeroish" when the pump is nearly at its limit). The different phase comes from the different path length between the screen and the two slits, and the beams are diffracted by the slits, not by some kind of lensing affect from the air near the slits. You're also wrong about the "lens" created by putting your fingers close together - that's also diffraction. You can read about diffraction around solid objects in the later chapters of any electrodynamics book.

Most light-based double slit experiments are not done in a vacuum because there's no point. Air does not significantly alter the paths of light beams. I'm sure there are numerous circumstances where an interference pattern still is somehow generated and used for something else inside a vacuum, but honestly I don't know how I'd search for such a thing on google. At this point the physics underlying the double slit experiment is so well established that nobody would try this and publish a paper just saying "I've checked that the double slit experiment with light still works in a vacuum."

However, all other double slit experiments with massive particles are done in vacuums. This is because collisions with gas ruin coherence and remove the interference pattern (actually funny enough, the exact opposite of your hypothesis). This can also be phrased as "a collision with gas measures the particle's position and determines which slit it went through, so it can no longer interfere with other possible paths."  Below I linked a nature article where its done with C-60 molecules. The vacuum is discussed in the second paragraph. They say they have a vacuum of $5\times10^{-7}\,\text{mbar}$, which gives a mean free path of $500\,\text{m}$. So the molecules definitely don't hit even one air molecule on their way to the detector. I also linked a historical article from 1961 about a double slit with electrons - the title is German but the abstract is english. It's actually a remarkably understandable abstract for such an old paper, and the vacuum is mentioned in the first sentence ($10^{-4}\,\mathrm{mbar}$; mean free path of $0.5\,\mathrm{m}$, which is marginal)

["Wave–particle duality of C60 molecules"](https://www.nature.com/articles/44348)

["Elektroneninterferenzen an mehreren künstlich hergestellten Feinspalten"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01342460)

Comment: With larger particles, do you know how they factor out the electrostatic interference of the particle moving close to the slit material. That's another factor I wonder about this set-up because I would imagine that if the particle gets close enough there could be an electron exchange due to the relative motion, proximity and the vacuum pressure making ionisation easier; that could also alter flight trajectories. Or even then just colisions with the slit in general. My understanding is direct observation "removes" the effect.

Comment: Electron diffraction of crystals in an SEM or TEM is done at low pressure (high to ultrahigh vacuum). Diffraction works just fine.